# Interact with dynamic Input Box using selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I am having a difficulty interact with dynamic input box using selenium. The input box is like this. The "Next" button is disabled, and there is no value in the input box by default. Once user click the input box, the  attribute will be generated in html, and the input box will show blue/red light based on acceptance rule.
[image]
[image]
When user finish typing and click some places else in page body, the input box lost focus, values in input box are recorded, and the "Next" button will be enabled.

[image]

I am having problem simulate this using selenium. As below, although I am able to sentkeys into the input box, but the input box is never highlighted, therefore even following code clicks page body, the "Next" is not enabled. My guess is there are some extra code evaluates user input(show red/blue light), and it triggers by keyboard or mouse actions, therefore selenium or javascript and sent in value but it won't trigger the complete reaction.

[image]

Here is my code. I tried sent in key board reaction ("Keys.SPACE"), but it does not help. I also tried sent in values using javascript or other selenium methods but nothing work. Any suggestions!?

```
    actions.moveToElement(getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(NEW_COLUMN + "td [last()]")))
            .click()
            .sendKeys(presetsTexName + Keys.SPACE + "dsf")
            .build()
            .perform();
    getElement(tagName("body")).click();
```

Comment: This is similar functionality with Gmail's To text box. Have you tried with Robot class of Java? `Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);`

Comment: @mk08 its not exactly same. Seems the text box needs get focus and be activated first, otherwise even javascript can sent value in, the box won't response to keyboard react.

Comment: Don't suppose you can share a link to the page?

Comment: Rather than `moveToElement()`, have you tried just `getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(NEW_COLUMN + "td [last()]")).sendKeys("some text")`? Maybe send a TAB to move out of the control?